# Collection view Cell Animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to animate UICollectionviewCells as they are created. I wanted to give each collectionviewcell a frame whose origin would be outside the phone and then I try to animate them, the way I wanted to do this was to use animate with duration and save their actual frames so that I can have the collectionviewCells animate to the so called "actual frames", the problem now is that, so I make one collectionViewcell in one section, so every collectionviewcell has "0" as its origin for the "actual frame", I won't be able to get the correct frames on the screen to animate a uicollectionview cell too. Would anyone have any suggestion for me to achieve the animation?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check this link: http://www.objc.io/issue-12/collectionview-animations.html.

The standardized idea is to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and then implement the method `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` to provide the initial positioning properties of the cells.

P.S. Other animations (when you remove a cell or when you rotate your device) are also talked about in the post. Read them if you are interested.

Comment: I was looking at this after you sent me the link but do you think its possible to animate an entire section?

Comment: I think it make no difference to animate the entire section. For example, you may first cache the attributes and then apply the same translating transform to the attributes of all indexPaths to get the initial attribute. This will make the entire section move to current position as a bunch. After all, it's just about how to set the initial layout attribute.